# Setting Eventbrite payment method

Tags: eventbrite

I want to set an Eventbrite event's payment method using the API. I need to do this for multiple accounts, and each account has different payment methods. Some accounts have more than one payment method.

The payment_update API call only lets you turn on/off PayPal, Google Merchant, check and cash. What about credit card merchant accounts? What about Authorize.Net?

The Eventbrite docs around payment and the API payment_update don't go into any detail or describe different scenarios.

My specific questions, at least for now:

- When I create a new event and an account has one payment method, does the event default to that payment method?
- When I create a new event and an account has more than one payment method, what is the default payment method for the event?
- How do I select a payment method that isn't one of the three in the payment_update API call (specifically, credit card account or Authorize.Net)?

If the Eventbrite docs talk about this, I haven't yet found them. A pointer to the proper M to RTF would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So, currently, choosing an alternate payment method (credit card, authorize.net) is not available. I think they're working on adding those features.

As for the default payment type, I can't be as much help there. My suggestion would be to set up an account with multiple payment types and try creating events to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, @phildini. My next thought is whether it would work to set up a default event and use event_copy, and if that would copy the payment information. I'll give that a try, but the combinations I'll have to try (different payment methods, if one is the default or it's selected randomly, etc.) makes me wish this was better documented.

Comment: An Eventbrite engineer replied directly to me, "I think your idea about using event_copy should work, since that does duplicate payment options. The other thing that may work depending on what you're doing is doing something per user: when you create a new event we copy your most recently published event's payment options for the new one, assuming that's your current "default". I'm 99% certain this does the same thing on the API, so that may also be an option." He added that the state of API support is in flux so it's difficult to get any API changes implemented right now.